# Is there a way in Google Apps Script to upload data and to open a new tab afterwards?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a Google Aops Script for Google Sheets to interface with our server.

We need to export the selected data and than to open a new browser tab (from our server).

Currently we have a button in the sidebar, which has a handler in GAS. This handler exports the data (via urlfetch) and appends an anchor (styled as a button) to the ui. This anchor opens a new tab from our server, when it is pressed by the user.

Is there a way to directly open the new tab from the GAS handler (without user action)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't open a new tab from a handler. A tab is only opened if the user willingly clicks on an anchor, any way around that is considered a security issue by the Apps Script team.

But you can add a handler to the anchor and process the click while the user navigates to the new tab. I'm not sure this will work for you though. If you have control of the targeted server, then you can add a spinner or something and have the user wait a little until the Apps Script backend sends you the data.

Here's an implementation using UiApp and a [library](https://sites.google.com/site/myappsscriptlibs/ui) I wrote a while ago.

```js
function linkAndHandler() {
  var app = UI.newApp('Link And Handler Test');
  UI.app.add(UI.lockAction(UI.anchor('Google.com', 'https://google.com'), 'linkHandler'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(UI.finish());
}

function linkHandler() {
  UI.app.add(UI.label('handler ran'));
}
```